# Post data of all inputs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, input

I do generate some `<input>`s with random names on the page (nearly ten at once).

Stuck on a question about submitting them.

I use this code to submit:

```
$('.table_data').submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    // some validation check and then

    $.post(url, {user_mail: mail}, function()
    {
        alert('done);
    });
});
```

The problem is, it submits `user_mail` only.

**How do I submit data of all `<input>`s?**

Have tried to use `$.post(url, function(){})`, it sends nothing.

Its possible to get all the inputs into array and then throw to the `$.post` function, but I'm not sure how to do it well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your form's classname is `table_data` then use this

```
$.post(url,$('.table_data').serialize(), function(){})
```

And you will get form input's `names` as key of your `global POST` array.

**Full code**

```
$('.table_data').submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    // some validation check and then

    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function()
    {
        alert('done');
    });
});
```

Read more on [$.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post(
   url,                  // url to submit
   $(this).serialize(),  // make a standard-looking query string using all inputs value
   function(response) {        
     // success function
     // in parameter response is to capture data send from capture
  },
  'json'  // dataTyep in which format you're accepting 
          // data from server may be html, xml ans so on
);
```

**Related refs:**

- [$.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize)
- [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

You are preventing the default behaviour on form submit using `event.preventDefault()` and then only sending the usermail value to server using ajax.

From what I understand, you need to serialize the form so that you can obtain all the names and their values and then send it to server. For that you need [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function in jQuery